# Mediaplayer setOnCompletionListener is calling repeatedly

Tags: android, listener, media-player, android-seekbar

In my application i am showing my audio files in listview, and when clicks on listitem particular file has to be played inside the listview cell with seekbar. But now i want to update the ui when playback finishes. 
I have used onCompletionListener, but it invokes repeatedly when playback starts.
    This is my code

```
private void startPlayBack(final MessagesAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder){

        try {

            if(mMediaPlayer!=null){
                if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                }
            }
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(viewHolder.mChatMessage.mMessages);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("audioplay", "IOException *************",e);
        }catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.i("audioplay", "IllegalStateException *************",e);
        }

        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                viewHolder.mAudioPlayBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.mAudioPlayBtn.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.audio_close));
                mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                Log.i("Completion Listener", "audio Completed");
            }
        });

        viewHolder.mAudioSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (mMediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
        });

        seekUpdation(viewHolder);
    }
```

This is the log information got,

```
08-20 07:28:24.099  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
08-20 07:28:24.099  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
08-20 07:28:24.099  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
08-20 07:28:24.103  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
08-20 07:28:24.107  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
08-20 07:28:24.107  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
08-20 07:28:25.739  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
08-20 07:28:26.415  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
08-20 07:28:26.415  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
08-20 07:28:26.419  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
08-20 07:28:26.419  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
08-20 07:28:27.323  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
08-20 07:28:27.959  14873-14873/com.cybosol.sabanet I/Completion Listener﹕ audio Completed
```

Comment: There might be an error in playing the audio. `setOnCompletionListener()` callback will be called in the case where the audio completes successfully, or if playback terminates due to an error.

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar problem when using `MediaPlayers` in a `ViewPager`.  It turned out the `MediaPlayers` were encountering an error, which was causing the `OnCompletionListener` to be called.  From the [OnErrorListener documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html):

> **Returns**
>
> True if the method handled the error, false if it didn't. Returning false, or not having an OnErrorListener at all, will cause the OnCompletionListener to be called.

Implement an `OnErrorListener` for your `MediaPlayers` to prevent extraneous calls to `OnCompletionListener`.